# Symfony 2: Class careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterQuestionHeading is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony

I am getting the above error after my entity name is correct and orm also. Why it is showing I am confused and didn't get the mapped superclass. Database table is also simple. Kindly help me out. 
                  I have used entity " MasterQuestionHeading " in the following class to fetch the records.

Here my code:

```
namespace careerFutura\AptitudeProfileBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\StudentRegistration;
use careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\StudentAnswer;
use careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterQuestionHeading;


class AptitudeProfileTestController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //return $this->render('careerFuturaAptitudeProfileBundle:Question:Aptitude_Profile_Test.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $session = $this->get('request')->getSession();
        $session->set('selected_tab','');
        $id_student = $session->get('id_student');

        $student_details = $em->getRepository('webBundle:StudentRegistration')->findBy(array('idStudent'=>$id_student));
        $id_qualification = $student_details[0]->gettestClass();

        if($id_student == ""){

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_security_logout'));
        }
        else{

            $test_1_number=array(); $test_2_number=array();
            $test_3_number=array();$test_4_number=array();
            $test_5_number=array();$test_6_number=array();
            $test_7_number=array();

            $test_1_answer=array(); $test_2_answer=array();
            $test_3_answer=array();$test_4_answer=array();
            $test_5_answer=array();$test_6_answer=array();
            $test_7_answer=array();

            //Define counters for each test.
            $test_1_counter=0;$test_2_counter=0;
            $test_3_counter=0;$test_4_counter=0;
            $test_5_counter=0;$test_6_counter=0;
            $test_7_counter=0;

            $trait_numbers = array();$trait_counters = array();
            $answer_array = array();$ans_array = array();

            //set video.
            $session->set('video_show',1);

            /**************************This is for test 1*********************/
            $test_1_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                    array(
                                           'idHeader'=>23,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                    array('sequence' =>'ASC'));


            foreach($test_1_question as $test1_que){

                array_push($test_1_number, $test1_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_1'=>$test_1_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_1_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_1_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_1_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_1'=>$test_1_counter);
           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);




        /**************************This is for test 2*********************/
            $test_2_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>24,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_2_question as $test2_que){

                array_push($test_2_number, $test2_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_2'=>$test_2_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_2_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_2_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_2_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_2'=>$test_2_counter);
           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);


           /**************************This is for test 3*********************/
            $test_3_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>25,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_3_question as $test3_que){

                array_push($test_3_number, $test3_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_3'=>$test_3_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_3_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_3_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_3_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_3'=>$test_3_counter);

           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);


           /**************************This is for test 4*********************/
            $test_4_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>26,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_4_question as $test4_que){

                array_push($test_4_number, $test4_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_4'=>$test_4_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_4_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_4_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_4_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_4'=>$test_4_counter);

           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);



            /**************************This is for test 5*********************/
            $test_5_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>27,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_5_question as $test5_que){

                array_push($test_5_number, $test5_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_5'=>$test_5_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_5_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_5_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_5_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_5'=>$test_5_counter);

           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);


            /**************************This is for test 6*********************/
            $test_6_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>28,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_6_question as $test6_que){

                array_push($test_6_number, $test6_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_6'=>$test_6_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_6_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_6_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_6_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_6'=>$test_6_counter);

           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);



            /**************************This is for test 7*********************/
            $test_7_question = $em->getRepository('webBundle:AptitudeQuestion')
                            ->findBy(
                                     array(
                                           'idHeader'=>29,
                                           'idQualification'=>$id_qualification
                                           ),
                                     array('sequence' => 'ASC'));


            foreach($test_7_question as $test7_que){

                array_push($test_7_number, $test7_que->getidAptitudeQuestion());


            }

            $row = array('Test_7'=>$test_7_number);

            $trait_numbers = array_merge((array)$trait_numbers, (array)$row);

            $test_7_answer = $em->getRepository('careerFuturaStudySkillsBundle:studentAnswer8th')
                                ->findBy(array('id_student' => $id_student,
                                               'id_qualification'=>$id_qualification,
                                               'id_test_type' => 9)
                                        );

            foreach($test_7_answer as $ans){

                if(!in_array($ans->getIdQuestion(), $array_array)){
                  $test_7_counter++;
                  array_push($array_array, $ans->getIdQuestion());  
                }// end if


            } // end foreach loop.


           $row = array('Test_7'=>$test_7_counter);

           $trait_counters = array_merge((array)$trait_counters, (array)$row);


           $status = $em->getRepository('webBundle:StudentTestStatus')
                        ->findBy(array('idStudent' => $id_student,
                                       'idTestType' => 9
                                      )
                                );


           $test_time = $em->getRepository('webBundle:MasterQuestionHeading')
                           ->findAll();  

            $test_times = array();$completed_trait = array();

            foreach($test_time as $time){
                foreach($status as $st){
                    if($time->getPriority() == $st->getPriority()){
                        if($st->getStatus() == 0){
                            $session->set('current_trait', $st->getPriority());
                        }else{                          
                            array_push($completed_trait,$st->getPriority());
                        }
                        $test_times[$time->getPriority()] = $st->getRemainingTime();
                    }else
                        $test_times[$time->getPriority()] = $time->gettestTime();
                }
            }
            if(sizeof($test_times) == 0){
                foreach($test_time as $time){
                    $test_times[$time->getPriority()] = $time->gettestTime();
                }
            }   

           return $this->render('AptitudeBundle:Question:index.html.twig',
                            array(
                                  'timing' => $test_times,
                                  'numbers' => $trait_numbers, 
                                  'counters' => $trait_counters, 
                                  //'answer' => $answer_string,
                                  'completed' => implode("|",$completed_trait), 
                                  'qualification' => $id_qualification
                                )
                            );    




        }//else end here

    }//end function here.

}// class end here
```

Here is my Entity COde:

```
<?php

namespace careerFutura\webBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterQuestionHeading
 */
class MasterQuestionHeading
{
    /**
     * @var integer $idHeader
     */
    private $idHeader;

    /**
     * @var integer $idQualification
     */
    private $idQualification;

    /**
     * @var string $heading
     */
    private $heading;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer $priority
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdon
     */
    private $createdon;

    /**
     * @var integer $createdby
     */
    private $createdby;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedon
     */
    private $updatedon;

    /**
     * @var integer $updatedby
     */
    private $updatedby;

    /**
     * @var integer $active
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var integer $version
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @var careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTesttype
     */
    private $idTestType;

    /**
     * @var careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTrait
     */
    private $idTrait;


    /**
     * Get idHeader
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdHeader()
    {
        return $this->idHeader;
    }

    /**
     * Set idQualification
     *
     * @param integer $idQualification
     */
    public function setIdQualification($idQualification)
    {
        $this->idQualification = $idQualification;
    }

    /**
     * Get idQualification
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdQualification()
    {
        return $this->idQualification;
    }

    /**
     * Set heading
     *
     * @param string $heading
     */
    public function setHeading($heading)
    {
        $this->heading = $heading;
    }

    /**
     * Get heading
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getHeading()
    {
        return $this->heading;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set priority
     *
     * @param integer $priority
     */
    public function setPriority($priority)
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;
    }

    /**
     * Get priority
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPriority()
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdon
     *
     * @param datetime $createdon
     */
    public function setCreatedon($createdon)
    {
        $this->createdon = $createdon;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdon
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getCreatedon()
    {
        return $this->createdon;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdby
     *
     * @param integer $createdby
     */
    public function setCreatedby($createdby)
    {
        $this->createdby = $createdby;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdby
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCreatedby()
    {
        return $this->createdby;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedon
     *
     * @param datetime $updatedon
     */
    public function setUpdatedon($updatedon)
    {
        $this->updatedon = $updatedon;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedon
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedon()
    {
        return $this->updatedon;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedby
     *
     * @param integer $updatedby
     */
    public function setUpdatedby($updatedby)
    {
        $this->updatedby = $updatedby;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedby
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUpdatedby()
    {
        return $this->updatedby;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param integer $active
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Set version
     *
     * @param integer $version
     */
    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;
    }

    /**
     * Get version
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    /**
     * Set idTestType
     *
     * @param careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTesttype $idTestType
     */
    public function setIdTestType(\careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTesttype $idTestType)
    {
        $this->idTestType = $idTestType;
    }

    /**
     * Get idTestType
     *
     * @return careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTesttype 
     */
    public function getIdTestType()
    {
        return $this->idTestType;
    }

    /**
     * Set idTrait
     *
     * @param careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTrait $idTrait
     */
    public function setIdTrait(\careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTrait $idTrait)
    {
        $this->idTrait = $idTrait;
    }

    /**
     * Get idTrait
     *
     * @return careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterTrait 
     */
    public function getIdTrait()
    {
        return $this->idTrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us helping you.

Comment: I have added the code.Please check it.

Comment: Also I have added my entity.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ORM\Entity` as shown below:

```
namespace careerFutura\webBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterQuestionHeading
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any annotation in this class. I think (based on your Controller) this class will not be a MappedSuperclass so you need to add `@ORM\Entity` and `@ORM\Id` to your code (and don't forget others variables).

```
<?php

namespace careerFutura\webBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * careerFutura\webBundle\Entity\MasterQuestionHeading
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MasterQuestionHeading
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type=integer)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```